# How can I replace the input character with the "*" character?

Tags: c++, cin

How can I replace the input character with the "*" character? Everything should happen at the time of entering (like entering a password when registering on the site).
Thanks for the answer!!!

Comment: You can't do that with just standard c++ directly. You need some OS api or library that makes use of an OS api.

Comment: Related/duplicates (I think these just remove echo, not replace it with stars): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899025/hide-user-input-on-password-prompt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413445/reading-a-password-from-stdcin

Comment: This question is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316562/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-password-defined-within-c-code

Comment: Loads of duplicates: https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&biw=1600&bih=789&sxsrf=ALeKk009fQoRQPc8i8OIGH_t57H1NFGWNg%3A1607704204747&ei=jJ7TX7X9LIvgkgWXrI_IAg&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+hide+password&oq=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22c%2B%2B%22+hide+password&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1Djrz5Y2M4-YL3UPmgAcAJ4AIABY4gBuwiSAQIxM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwi185vwrMbtAhULsKQKHRfWAykQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show enter password in the form of Asterisks(\*) on terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990966/how-to-show-enter-password-in-the-form-of-asterisks-on-terminal)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

An easiest way, i think like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    char ch;
    std::cout << "enter the text: ";
    while((ch = _getch()) != 13) //enter type
    {
        str+= ch;
        std::cout << '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: This could work on windows but probably not other OSs.

Comment: I did not downvote however I assume there are at least two reasons someone would. The first reason is the person asking never mentioned that they we using MS windows instead of Android or some other OS. A second reason is there is no description of the code.